# Custom python package not found

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I followed this tutorial from 
[python.org](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/)
and managed to upload to PyPI and install with pip but all I get is

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tomaszslittlehelpers'`

Any suggestions?

The import works locally that is when imported from a file in a folder above.

package name is `tomaszslittlehelpers`

`setup.py`:

```
import setuptools

with open('README.md', 'r') as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
        name='tomaszslittlehelpers',
        version='0.0.2',
        author='TomaszAndrzej',
        author_email='',
        description='Tomasz\'s Little Helpers',
        long_description=long_description,
        long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
        url='',
        packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
        classifiers=[
                'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
                'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
                'Operating System :: OS Independent',
                ],
        python_requires='>=3.7',

        )
```

`__init__.py`:

```
name='tomaszslittlehelpers'
```

Project tree:

```
tomaszslittlehelpers
    build
        bdist.win-amd64
    dist
        tomaszslittlehelpers-0.0.2-py3-none-any.whl
        tomaszslittlehelpers-0.0.2.tar.gz
    tomaszslittlehelpers.egg-info
        dependency_links.txt
        PKG-INFO
        SOURCES.txt
        top_level.txt
    __init__.py
    LICENSE
    README.md
    setup.py
```

`pip install tomaszslittlehelpers`

installs into

`C:\users ... \python37\Lib\site-packages\tomaszslittlehelpers-0.0.1.dist-info`
there is no `tomaszslittlehelpers` folder

Comment: Hi @Tomasz. It'd be good to get more specifics on this. What is the package called on PyPI? Please also share the `setup.py` file so we can see how you're attempting to build it.

Comment: It sounds like an issue with the location of the installed package.  
I can see the package on pypi.org so it must be an issue with where the package is installed locally.

Comment: where does it install to

Comment: Somewhere along the way you did something like `python setup.py build` to create an archive in `dist/` that you uploaded, right? I'd bet that the package you created has no Python files in it because `setuptools.find_packages()` didn't find anything.

Comment: If you can show the directory tree of your project that would help. You probably want an empty  `tomaszslittlehelpers/__init__.py` in your package.

Comment: look at sinoroc's answer

Answer (score 10):

There is an issue with your packaging. Your code is not added to your distributions. You are using `packages=setuptools.find_packages(),` but there doesn't seem to be any package to look for. It looks like your code is in the `__init__.py` file at the root of your project. This most likely won't work.

Two solutions:

- Rename your `__init__.py` to `tomaszslittlehelpers.py` and replace `packages=setuptools.find_packages(),` with `py_modules=['tomaszslittlehelpers'],`.
- Move your `__init__.py` to a `tomaszslittlehelpers` subdirectory, and `find_packages()` should be able to find it.

In both cases you should then be able to import your code like this: `import tomaszslittlehelpers`.

Answer (score -1):

If you look on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/tomaszslittlehelpers/#files) and download your [release](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/43/39/bbb5741dc86a5ea5b67348b044c2c2f03e2ec5f200169d915a7b660fbc32/tomaszslittlehelpers-0.0.2.tar.gz)
You can see that in this release there are no python files included

As @kirk-strauser mentioned. This is most likely because `setuptools.find_packages()` didn't find any packages